# Play2 scala specs2 test FakeRequest with remote address

Tags: scala, playframework-2.4

I'm working with Play! 2.4 scala, spec2 and Mockito.

I'm trying to set the remote address of a fake request in one of my integration tests but I can't found the right way to do that.

I would like to do something similar to the following snippet of code (that does not compile):

```
route(FakeRequest(GET, "/users/geographicPoint", remoteAddress =  "81.xxx.xxx.xxx"))
```

How can I easily do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FakeRequest.apply` does not have an overload that accepts only those three parameters. The case class itself has some parameters without defaults that you would have to fill in. (Before editing) I would say you could just use the `copy` method, since `FakeRequest` is a case class, then fill in the value you want. But annoyingly, the `copy` method is inherited from `RequestHeader`, so when you `copy` a `FakeRequest`, you do not get a `FakeRequest` in return. Instead, you have to invoke the constructor manually:

```
import play.api.mvc.AnyContentAsEmpty

new FakeRequest("GET", "/", FakeHeaders(), AnyContentAsEmpty, remoteAddress = "1.2.3.4")
```

Comment: thanks, 
I already tried that but I get the followed error :

`type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.mvc.RequestHeader
[error]  required: play.api.mvc.Request[?]
[error]         FakeRequest(GET, "/users/geographicPoint").copy(remoteAddress = "81.xxx.xxx.xxx"))`

Comment: @LoannDelgado You're right. That's pretty annoying that it returns `RequestHeader`.

Answer (score 0):

```
FakeRequest(GET, "/users/geographicPoint").copyFakeRequest(remoteAddress = "81.xxx.xxx.xxx") . worked for me.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.